# Update a file depending on last modified, using Python

Tags: python, operating-system

During a running flow, I get a path to a file *x*.

As a defense mechanism, since it's a part of code that might crash often and rerun itself, after I get this path *x*, I wish to check this file and see If it was last modified in the last hour.

If it was updated/ changed in the last hour, it means this service is rerunning after a crash and I do not want to call `update_file(x, new_data)`.

If it was updated more than an hour ago, it means I want to override this file with the new data and call `update_file(x, new_data)`.

Comment: maybe this can help https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime. But please explain a bit more what you expect  and what you've already tried

Comment: what have you tried and how the results were different from what you expected?

Comment: I managed to get the time, but I was not successful with comparing that time and now, as @lenik showed in his answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import os, time

if os.path.getmtime( x ) + 3600 < time.time() :
    update_the_file( ... )
else :
    # don't update
    pass
```